How to pass List of data from NavGraph in android kotlin Android
Getting this error:
Type mismatch: inferred type is List<BookParkingResponse.Data> but List<BookParkingResponse.Data.ParkingRequests> was expected
unable to pass data bewteeen fragments
Nav Graph code:
navGraph
        <argument
            android:name="bookingRequestList"
            app:argType="com.jvm.di.model.parkingSpot.response.BookParkingResponse.Data" />

Response class
@Parcelize
data class BookParkingResponse(
    @SerializedName("data") var data: List<Data>? = null
):Parcelable {
    @Parcelize
    data class Data(
        @SerializedName("parkingRequests") var parkingRequests: List<ParkingRequests>? = null
    ) : Parcelable {
        @Parcelize
        data class ParkingRequests(
            @SerializedName("parkingSpotId") var parkingSpotId: Int? = null,
            @SerializedName("bookingStatus") var bookingStatus: String? = null,
            @SerializedName("amount") var amount: Double? = null):Parcelable
}

// pass data on itemClick 
 findNavController().navigate( MyParkFragmentDirections.toAllRequestListFragment(it))


// how I receive data in another fragments
private val args: AllRequestListFragmentArgs by navArgs()
 allRequestListAdapter = AllRequestListAdapter()
            rvItems.adapter = allRequestListAdapter
            allRequestListAdapter.allParkingRequestList = listOf(args.bookingRequestList)

// how i create list in adapter 
 internal var allParkingRequestList: List<BookParkingResponse.Data> by Delegates.observable(
        emptyList()
    ) { _, _, _ -> notifyDataSetChanged() }


Can you share the full code as findNavController().navigate(MyParkFragmentDirections.toAllRequestListFragment(it)) here we don't know what you are passing as it

So, Basically when i pass (it) means i am passing BookParkingResponse.Data.
as i above mention

my argument type is BookParkingResponse.Data so, i have to pass this when i navigate to allRequestFragment.

i know that but i want to see what data are you sending as it, i know expected data is bookingRequestList. Please share whole code so we can help you figure out your porblem.

So u wrote on item Click here i think you are passing the specific item that is clicked in the navigation argument and hence mismatch error is displayed. hence to exactly figure out what's wrong please share whole code of each fragment individually

So, I resolve my issue.
corrected navgraph
<argument
            android:name="bookingRequestList"  app:argType="di.model.parkingSpot.response.BookParkingResponse$Data[]"/>

// this is how i pass the data
 findNavController().navigate(
                    MyParkFragmentDirections.toAllRequestListFragment(
                        it.parkingSpot?.parkingName!!,
                        arrayOf(it)
                    )
                )

So, this is the easy way to pass data, but what type of data is in our model class? what fragment was sent to the adapter and what type of data the adapter wants. it's a little bit tricky but when you understand. then it will become very easy for you

You should write below code
app:argType="com.jvm.di.model.parkingSpot.response.BookParkingResponse.Data.ParkingRequests"

